# MQL5 - Launching a form embedded in a DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, mql5

In MetaTrader 4/MQL4 I'm able to display a non-modal form (i.e., simple window with string grid) and pass data to this form from an indicator using the DLL interface. Been doing this for a while now and it works perfectly.

Trying to accomplish the same thing in MetaTrader 5/MQL5 but having some trouble. The form displays but immediately goes into an unresponsive state (application not responding).

I did run a test using the same 64-bit DLL on a different 64-bit platform (eSignal 12) and the form loads just fine.

I am using Delphi XE5 Update 2 to build the DLLs. 32-bit for MT4 and 64-bit for MT5. MT5 build is 1881. I created a very simple MQL5 script and Delphi DLL to test it:

**MQL5**

```
#import "TestForm.dll"
int showAForm(int hwnd);
int closeAForm();
#import

void OnStart()
  {
//---
   int hwnd=ChartGetInteger(0,CHART_WINDOW_HANDLE,0);
   showAForm(hwnd);
   Sleep(5000);
   closeAForm();
//---
  }
```

**Delphi**

```
library TestForm;

uses
    System.SysUtils,
    System.Classes,
    Windows,
    Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

var
    myForm: TForm;

function showAForm(handle: HWND): integer; stdCall;
var
    myHandle: HWND;
begin
    myHandle := FindWindow('MetaQuotes::MetaTrader::5.00', nil);
    showMessage(IntToStr(myHandle));
    try
        myForm := TForm.Create(nil);
        // myForm:=TForm.CreateParented(myHandle);
        // Windows.SetParent(myForm.Handle, myHandle);
        myForm.Show;
        result := 1;
    except
        result := -2;
    end;
end;

function closeAForm(): integer; stdCall;
begin
    myForm.Close();
    FreeAndNil(myForm);
    result := 1;
end;

exports
    showAForm,
    closeAForm;

begin
    IsMultiThread := true;
end.
```

I have tried a few different methods of creating the form (nil, parented) but it makes no difference. If I use ShowModal instead of Show the form displays correctly but of course the MT5 GUI is blocked.

No exceptions are generated, and both functions return correctly...it is just that the form itself will not display. Would be grateful if anyone could shed some light on what may be going on, and any possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
showAForm(hwnd);
Sleep(5000);
closeAForm();
```

Your `Sleep(5000);` blocks the GUI thread for full 5 seconds.

So you create the form `showAForm()`, block the GUI thread for 5 seconds, then close the form `closeAForm()`.

The Delphi form needs a working message pump to be able to work properly,
but the `Sleep(5000);` blocks the thread and doesn't let the message pump to operate.

In Delphi applications, eg. "mydelphiapp.exe", the Application.ProcessMessage function handles a message, and inside the Application.Run procedure, there is code like:

`repeat
        try
          HandleMessage;
        except
          HandleException(Self);
        end;
      until Terminated;`

To solve the problem, you need to build in Delphi, a message-pumping alternative to `Sleep()`:

```
procedure MessagePumpingSleep(ADelay:Longword); stdcall;
var
  T1, T2, dT : Longword;

begin
  T1 := GetTickCount;
  repeat
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    Sleep(1);  // this will stop this procedure from consuming 100% CPU.

    T2 := GetTickCount;
    dT := T2 - T1;
  until dT >= ADelay;
end;

exports MessagePumpingSleep;
```

Then call `MessagePumpingSleep(5000)` instead of `Sleep(5000);`

Obviously, to be able to call `MessagePumpingSleep(5000)`, you need to write the proper import code in MQL5 to import the `MessagePumpingSleep()` -function from the Delphi DLL.